# Supporting HTTPS on an ASP.NET application behind an IIS urlrewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, reverse-proxy

I have some ASP.NET (framework 4.8) applications that will be accessed over HTTP and HTTPS. And I want to ensure cookies etc. are configured correctly for this. e.g. session cookies for https has the `secure` flag set.

1. Local LAN directly over local HTTP bypassing, e.g: http://localhost:12345/mypage?fruit=apple. Cookies should not have the "secure" flag set.
2. HTTP to a public IIS that will rewrite to the local application over HTTP, e.g. http://example.com/myapp/mypage?fruit=apple. Cookies should not have the "secure" flag set.
3. HTTPS to a public IIS that will rewrite to the local application over HTTP, e.g. https://example.com/myapp/mypage?fruit=apple. Cookies *should* have the "secure" flag set. So IIS will have the certificate for TLS, handle renewal, SNI, etc.

Coming from NGINX/Rails/etc., I believe the `X-Forwarded-Proto` is the main one here, but this doesn't appear to be built in to the same extent here e.g. I might have:

```
location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
}
```

What is the correct configuration to add to IIS and the ASP.NET application to ensure security etc.?

Is it a concern if users add their own headers values in any of the cases?

---

So far I have the following:

web.config for IIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>                
                <rule name="Forward Https">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto" value="https" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="My App" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="myapp/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:12345/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
```

`<allowedServerVariables>` didn't seem to be allowed, so added `HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto` in the IIS GUI.

Application:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Nothing built in?
    appBuilder.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == "https")
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        }
        return next();
    });
    // Cookie shared between different applications!
    appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        CookieName = ".ASPXAUTH",
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
        CookiePath = "/",
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest // Did not appear to use X-Forwarded-Proto
    });
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    // ... other config stuff
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController // System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    public string  Get(int id)
    {
        // response.Headers.AddCookies(cookie);
        Request.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "MyValue", new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = Microsoft.Owin.SameSiteMode.Lax,
            Path = "/",
            Secure = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.IsSecure // "SameAsRequest"
        });
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to secure iis, you can use [SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis), if you want to [secure asp.net](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/asp-net-security-overview-7c8562d3-7bea-306c-4c78-98dd6c6993b3), then you can use authentication, etc.

Comment: @samwu Well so that is what this is doing, IIS has the TLS/SSL/HTTPS enabled, but it needs to tell the ASP.net application that, because it can influence the `Set-Cookie` etc. headers being generated (as well as any urls/links that are presented in absolute form rather than relative).